# Received fine for parking - court appearance not required - now not payable

Tags: usa, automobiles

I was in the USA (New York) for a visit and my car got towed. I parked in a non-marked disabled parking lot (“sorry sir, but we thought you're a resident… and they know…”). The police released the car and told me to pay the fine online a few days after. Court appearance required is not marked on the fine (there is a field for it). And they told me, no you can pay online.

Now when I want to pay online, it says that the fine is not payable and court appearance is required. What should I do now? I am back in Dubai and can not fly to the US for such a small thing. What should I do?

Comment: could you post a picture of the ticket?

Comment: Who owns the car?

Comment: How long ago did you receive the ticket?

Comment: Typically the rental company will bill you an (inflated) administrative fee for unpaid tickets or tolls - check your CC bill, and check your rentral contract for how much the rental co's administrative fee is, and they don't notify you or explain it, they just stick an unexplained charge on your CC. Sometimes the rental co's billing happens several months later. (It's usually in your interest if you were able to directly pay the ticket yourself with the court before the deadline, check when that deadline was.)

Answer (score 1):

A parking ticket in the US is issued to the registered owner of the car. Since your ticket was issued to the rental car company, it's the rental company's ticket. The rental company has already settled the ticket with the court, and you've already settled with the rental company. If either the rental company or the court told you that you don't have to appear, then you are okay.